# Find the largest number with greedy method

Tags: c, greedy

I am new to programming and I have to do a little program that has an array of **n** elements to find the largest 4 numbers and then calculate the sum of them.

Thanks for your help!

As an example:
input is `3 7 8 1 6 9 8 5`
output: `9 8 8 7` sum `32`

What I am getting is output of **9 8 7 6** (doesn't display 8 for the second time)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int maxim(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b)
       return a;
    else 
       return b;
}

int main() {
    int i, j, n, a[999], m, aux, sum = 0, v[999], k = 0, x[999], c, t = 0, q, r;
    int max = 0;

    printf("No. of objects (type 8): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nNo. of objects for first place (type 4): ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    r = m;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
        }
    }
    x[0] = max;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) { 
        max = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] > max && a[j] < x[i - 1]) {
                max = a[j];
            }
        }
        x[i] = max;
    }

    for (t = 0; t < m; t++) {
        printf("%d", x[t]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question or issue?

Comment: You are checking that the next max number should be less than any previous max number: `if(a[j] > max && a[j] < x[i - 1])`. This will remove any duplicates in the result hence it cannot choose `9 8 8 7` since the second 8 is not less than the first 8. This approach will not work. You need to change your approach.

Comment: @Deddy my issue is that the program doesn't take as output the duplicated numbers from the input (as in the eg.)

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen how should i change the code? Can you give me an idea? It took me 2 weeks to get to where i am now. If i use ```if(a[j] >= max && a[j] <= x[i - 1])``` the output is 9999

Comment: Please, edit your question and indent the code properly.  Be ordered and write code that can be read easily.  Don't create so large lists of variables and name them based on the meaning of the values stored on them, and try to give meaningful names to all objects in your program.  You'll see that you understand more easily your algorithm, and properly you get to the solution alone.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the four largest numbers can be done with an auxiliary 4 element array.  You fill it at the beginning with the first four numbers, and you calculate the minimum of those.... then you iterate the array (from the fifth number) checking if it is larger than the minimum, if it is, you exchange the number with it, and calculate again the minimun value of the 4 element array.  Once you are finished, you will have the 4 largest numbers in the array.  On this last loop, you can also compute the sum of the obtained numbers.

A possible solution, employing as the 4 element array the first four elements of the original array is below (those first positions are already included in the array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N   4

int array[] = {3, 7, 8, 1, 6, 9, 8, 5};
int array_count = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];

int main()
{
    for (int i = N; i < array_count; i++) {
        /* first, determine the minimum element of the first four
         */
        int i_min = 0, min = array[0];
        for (int j = 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (min > array[j]) {
                i_min = j;
                min = array[j];
            }
        }
        /* i_min has the index and min is the minimum of the four
         * first elements */
        if (array[i_min] < array[i]) { /* need to exchange */
            int temp = array[i_min];
            array[i_min] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    char *sep = "";
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
        printf("%s%d", sep, array[i]);
        sep = ", ";
    }
    printf("\nsum=%d\n", sum);
}
```

The solution it prints, for the proposed array is:

```
$ findfourmax 
9, 7, 8, 8
sum=32
$ _
```